# Using Visual studio I lost my code when the branch was deleted

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-code, delete-file

> Working on a project I changed Branches or something and it deleted my code!

[image]

**How do I get my code back?**

<sub>I'm writing this to help others, upvote if this Q & A saved your day!</sub>

Comment: Not to take anything away from your Q/A's usefulness, but this has nothing to do with git. This is *avoiding* using git. To be un-tagged `git` ? Used correctly, git prevents this situation from ever happening (recovering code from a deleted branch is quite trivial).

Comment: I'll update tag's, you're right, thanks. I hope people realise it's promoted to answer your own questions for the community.

Comment: Absolutely. I don't get the reason for the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply reverse engineering the compiled binaries in the bin folder. I personally prefer **[ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy)** over RedGates Reflector as its FREE!

It's easy, open the bin folder and Drag/Drop the `Test.DLL` or which ever DLL that you've lost the code into **[ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy)**:

[image]

Save Code to a Temp folder and it will recover your lost code!